# How to run/compile Pascal on Visual Studio Code SERVER? (FPC on Ubuntu?)

Tags: visual-studio-code, compiler-errors, ubuntu-16.04, freepascal

I had the idea to host my own visual studio code server cuz I am not able to install anything at work.
It works perfectly fine on Ubuntu 16.04.6 x64 - but how can I run/compile my Pascal code on it? https://i.stack.imgur.com/ng4wP.png

I've tried to install the extention 'Code Runner' but I get the error https://i.stack.imgur.com/Q8OU5.png - unfortunately I'm quite new to linux and have no clue how I can install FPC on it - everything related to pascal seems outdated.

How an I install FPC on my Ubuntu server to run my pascal code?

Comment: You can't install anything at work, or you are not allowed to? Anyway, please don't post error messages as image. Paste them as text.

Answer (score 1):

Download Lazarus (https://www.lazarus-ide.org/index.php?page=downloads) - it is the modern IDE for compiling, running and debugging pascal code in fpc.  It comes with an install package for fpc.  It supports a number of platforms including Linux and Windows, and the Linux distro even runs on Raspbian, the Linux which runs on the Raspberry Pi.

See also

https://www.lazarus-ide.org/ for general info;

https://forum.lazarus.freepascal.org/index.php?action=forum for a very active sopport community; and

http://wiki.lazarus.freepascal.org/ for extensive on-line documentation.

I used Delphi, the Windows package Lazarus and FPC are based on, for my main development work, but have never had any major problem using Lazarus + fpc when I needed a gui app which would run on Linux.  It's straightforward to run it in an Ubuntu running in a VMWare VM running on a Windows host.

Comment: Thanks for all the information! can I just follow this http://wiki.freepascal.org/How_to_setup_a_FPC_and_Lazarus_Ubuntu_repository to install it - since I only have a console? (irritates me a lot tbh) - how would you do it?

Comment: You only have a console? Why are you making life so hard?

Comment: @NAVE: Ubuntu can have a proper desktop. It also has a visual package manager that allows you to install software like FreePascal or Lazarus easily. But if it can run VSCode, it should have a GUI, right?